# how can I get a random generation of yes and no?

Tags: python, random

how can I get a random generation of yes and no?
and result store in dataframe column.

I want to the random generation of yes and no and store value in the column
but still not successful...
here is my code, it's working well but does not store the same result in the column.

```py
import string
import random
l1 = ["yes", "no"]
for x in range(8):
    rand = random.randint(0, 1)
    print(l1[rand])
```

Comment: store the value in what column?

Comment: Also consider using numpy. `import numpy as np; np.random.choice(['yes','no'], size=5)`

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen Importing a heavyweight library like `numpy` just to create some random numbers seems like overkill. A simple `[random.choice(['yes', 'no ']) for _ in range(5)]` will do.

Comment: @Matthias Fair point. On the other hands we don't know if performance is a consideration to OP so it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mylist = ['yes', 'no']

#Since you mentioned dataframe, I'm assuming you have a file path and a dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl', index_col=None)

for i in range(8):
    output = random.choice(mylist)

    # Save Record in a dictionary first assuming you already have a 'Random' column in your dataframe
    record_data_dict = {'Random': output}

    #append dictionary to the dataframe
    df = df.append(record_data_dict, ignore_index=True)
    
    # save the updated dataframe to the excel file
    df.to_excel(file_path, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list and `append()` to save values of the answer:

```
import string
import random
l1 = ["yes", "no"]

ans = [] # This for saving value of the answer
for x in range(8):
    rand = random.randint(0, 1)
    ans.append(l1[rand]) # Add random value to ans list
    print(l1[rand])

for i in ans:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['Churn']= np.random.choice(['yes','no'], len(df), p=[.7,.3])`

here `'churn'` is a column name and `df` is a data frame

It solved my problem.